# How do I update a D3 graphic in realtime?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a line+area chart displaying two different datasets. I don't want to append new data, I want instead to change the chart values often. How can I do this?

When I get new data, I update the scale and axis accordingly, and try to update the lines, but I endup with either a lot of old point, or none.

This is my attempt:

http://codepen.io/mrlinx/pen/LGvrGw

```
var data =  [
    [{'x':0,'y':10},{'x':1,'y':12},{'x':2,'y':17},{'x':3,'y':9},{'x':4,'y':10},{'x':5,'y':13},{'x':6,'y':13},{'x':7,'y':15},{'x':8,'y':16},{'x':9,'y':16}, {'x':10,'y':17}, {'x':11,'y':17}, {'x':12,'y':0}], 
  [{'x':0,'y':1},{'x':1,'y':1},{'x':2,'y':2},{'x':3,'y':3},{'x':4,'y':2},{'x':5,'y':8},{'x':6,'y':6},{'x':7,'y':4},{'x':8,'y':6},{'x':9,'y':7}, {'x':10,'y':9}, {'x':11,'y':5}, {'x':12,'y':3}]
];

var colors = [
    '#ec4863', 'blue'
]


//************************************************************
// Create Margins and Axis
//************************************************************
var margin = {top: 20, right: 30, bottom: 30, left: 50},
    width = 700 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 300 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var x = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([1, 8])
    .range([0, width]);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, 20])
    .range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .tickSize(0)
    .tickPadding(15)    
    .tickSubdivide(true)    
    .orient("bottom")
    .tickValues(d3.range(1, 8, 1)); 

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .tickPadding(15)
    .tickSize(-width)
    .tickSubdivide(true)    
    .orient("left")
.tickValues(d3.range(0, 21, 5));

var area = d3.svg.area()
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
    .y0(height)
    .y1(function(d) { return y(d.close); });    





//************************************************************
// Generate our SVG object
//************************************************************  
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(xAxis);

svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .call(yAxis);

svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .append("text")
    .attr("class", "axis-label")
    .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
    .attr("y", (-margin.left) + 10)
    .attr("x", -height/2);

svg.append("clipPath")
    .attr("id", "clip")
    .append("rect")
    .attr("width", width + 10)
    .attr("height", height);





//************************************************************
// Create D3 line object and draw data on our SVG object
//************************************************************
var line = d3.svg.area()
    .interpolate("monotone")    
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.x); })
    .y0(height)
    .y1(function(d) { return y(d.y); });        

svg.selectAll('.line')
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("path")
    .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)")
    .attr('stroke', function(d,i){          
  console.log(i);
        return colors[i%colors.length];
    })
.attr('fill', function(d,i){            
        return colors[i % colors.length];
    })
    .attr("d", line);       


//************************************************************
// Draw points on SVG object based on the data given
//************************************************************
var points = svg.selectAll('.dots')
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("g")
    .attr("class", "dots")
    .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)");   

points.selectAll('.dot')
    .data(function(d, index){       
        var a = [];
        d.forEach(function(point,i){
            a.push({'index': index, 'point': point});
        });     
        return a;
    })
    .enter()
    .append('circle')
    .attr('class','dot')
    .attr("r", 4)
    .attr('fill', function(d,i){    
        return colors[d.index%colors.length];
    })  
    .attr("transform", function(d) { 
        return "translate(" + x(d.point.x) + "," + y(d.point.y) + ")"; }
    );


function update() {

  var newValue = Math.random() * 20;

  var arrSize = data[0].length;

  data[0][arrSize-1].y = newValue;

  console.log(data);

  svg.selectAll('.dots').data(data).enter();
}




setInterval(function() {
  update();
}, 1500);
```

Comment: This example might help https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1642874

Comment: Thats helpful, but It doesn't seem to work for the 'dots' :/

Comment: Check out https://bost.ocks.org/mike/join/ to fully understand how data joins work in d3. You should not be calling selection.data().enter() to update existing data bindings. Instead, just use the update selection returned from selection.data() for updates

Comment: Still no luck. If I just update like that I can't create new elements.